# How do I maintain SEO ranking while migrating from a webapp to a CMS

Tags: seo, migration

I have a Node.js webapp with high ranking SEO that has about ten pages (example.com/blog) that contain static content. I want to move the app part to a subdomain (app.example.com), and replace the existing parent domain with a CMS where my client can easily write content.

For the static pages, I can keep the exact same URL structure (example.com/blog). Apart from this what steps do I need to take in order to maintain SEO rankings?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping URL structure will do most of the job but still you need to consider following things to maintain or improve the ranking:

- Maintain the image alt tags as it is
- Maintain the page metas as it is. You can use 'Fetch as Google' to compare whether google is seeing any page difference or not.
- You might need to use additional tools in your search console to see whether migration has any impact on discovery or performance of the new cms based blog.
- You need to reconfigure `robot.txt` file through cms.
- In case you are migrating to CMS, theme plays very much important role. There is nothing much that can be done for that to be frank. But you can analyse the theme for SEO compatibility before final upload.

If you consider above things, then I guess it will be more than enough to proceed with migration without affecting your existing ranking.